# How to convert an string dot notation in to an object reference, not nested

Tags: javascript, string, object, notation

I'm mapping an array in `react` to get a list of `jsx <label>` and `<input>` but each element has its own style that matches with result element. How do I convert string name to object reference?

```
render() {

    const elements = this.props.elements;
    console.log('render ' + this.props.selected)
    const elementList = elements.map(**elem** => (
        < div key={elem} className={styles.Inputs} >
            <label className={styles.{**elem**}}>
                <span className={this.state.selected === elem ? styles.red : styles.gray}></span>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="react-tips"
                    value={elem}
                    extra={this.state.selected}
                    checked={this.state.selected === elem}
                    onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
                    className="form-check-input"
                />
            </label>
        </div >
    ))
    return (
        <div>
            {elementList}
        </div>

    )
```

Comment: Hi Luis, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Inline style no work for me because i'm using pseudo notation (:before). so I'm implementing css modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
// To convert Object to String
let str = JSON.stringify(object); // Object could be Array or an Custom Object

// To convert  String back to Object
object = JSON.parse(str);
```

Hope this helps of tell me if I misunderstood the question

Comment: Sorry no work for me, I'm not using inline style, I'm using CSS modules instead. Here's my complete code: github.com/luifo/input-radio-with-icon-react.git

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this,

```
<label className={styles[**elem**]}>
```

Comment: Sorry no work for me, I'm usin css modules here's my complete code: https://github.com/luifo/input-radio-with-icon-react.git

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set object property and get the value dynamically, you can use [](third bracket) instead of .(dot). In your case it should be

```
<label className={styles[**elem**]}>
```

As an example, suppose you have a object like this

```
let obj = {
  1: 'One',
  2: 'Two',
  3: 'Three'
}
```

If you want to get the value dynamically using loop(just an example), you can get it like this

```
for(let i = 1; i <= Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
  console.log(obj[i]);
}
// Output
// 'One'
// 'Two'
// 'Three'
```

Comment: Sorry no work for me, I'm usin css modules here's my complete code: https://github.com/luifo/input-radio-with-icon-react.git

Comment: Object works exactly the same way i mentioned, may be you had a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solves guys. I just use standard css imported file to skip dot notation from css modules, not perfect but work very well. Thank you all

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './InputsRadio.module.css';
import './styles.css';

export default class List extends Component {

    state = {
        elements: [],
        selected: null
    }
    state = {

    };
    handleOptionChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            selected: event.target.value
        });
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        const selected = this.props.selected;
        this.setState({
            selected: selected
        });
    }



    render() {

        const elements = this.props.elements;
        console.log('render ' + this.props.selected)
        const elementList = elements.map(elem => (
            < div key={elem} className={styles.Inputs} >
                {console.log(styles[elem])}
                <label className={styles.Inputs}>
                    <span className={this.state.selected === elem ? `${elem} ${styles.red}` : `${elem} ${styles.gray}`}></span>
                    <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="react-tips"
                        value={elem}
                        extra={this.state.selected}
                        checked={this.state.selected === elem}
                        onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
                        className="form-check-input"
                    />
                </label>
            </div >
        ))
        return (
            <div>
                {elementList}
            </div>

        )

    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```